# Movie about underground creatures

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I don't remember much about the movie, but I know it came out a while ago.  The most I remember about the plot is an earthquake causes creatures from underground to attack residents of a city hotel. I believe it focuses heavily on a father and son with survivors of the attacks. In the end they make it out of the hotel to find giant crystals coming out of the ground and neighboring buildings under attack.

Comment: A look at our [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) to asking story id questions may be helpful in jogging your memory for more pertinent details.

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/list/ls050510252/ - One of these, presumably. Earthquakes releasing big nasties is a pretty common trope in B-Movies of the 1950s and 60s.

Comment: When is "a while ago"? Was the film in colour or black&white? What did the creatures look like? What was the budget like? Who were the actors? How old was the father, how old was the son? Where was the mother? Why were they in a hotel? Did they receive help from the outside world?

Comment: If the correct answer is posted, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: I didn't even notice how old this question was.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is the 2009 film *[The Blackout](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1489946/?ref_=m_rw_urv)* as per [2000s Movie about creatures coming from Basement drain of Apartment Building](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236920/2000s-movie-about-creatures-coming-from-basement-drain-of-apartment-building/236926#236926)

From [this review](https://m.imdb.com/review/rw2158544/?ref_=tt_urv) (bolding mine):

> it's Christmas eve and westphalia is under **quakes** and severe high temperatures with power surges going around the city( Los Angeles that is) . Scientists can't figure it out. There's a Christmas party in a **tenement block**, and the couples presented are living in the same building - 1 family (man + woman + man's brother + 2 kids boy and girl) , 1 about-to-get-divorced-couple, 1 about-to-get-married-couple, and some random dudes and girls. The newsman tells the power-surges are connected with the temperature and the quakes.
>
> Mom and dad are trying to have fun(in bed) but the kids find them out and they get sent to the **basement** to bring up their presents. **Nasty creature** eats their guts.
>
> There's an agoraphobic guy at the 2nd floor, friend with the superintendent and the electrician, and he's a master in discovery channel and electronics and communications. Electrician "Ralph" gets torn to bits. The party is ruined, more creatures come and claim lives. Some guy's brother tries something he saw on TV ("Hey the creatures might be photosensitive" ) but he gets a big head-shot and dies. The little girl is not dead - apparently she managed to survive ( somehow I have no idea ) and she got in a defunct elevator ( again HOW is a big question ). The group manages to kill 2 creatures, find out the main building entrance is blocked and head for the roof. They go through that defunct elevator's shaft and find out the little girl.
>
> The dad and dad's brother end up dead, and tadam: 3 survivors - The mom, the little girl and that agoraphobic fat guy. They get to the roof where they see LA has been torn apart by some **nasty volcano-type spikes** ( ?!WTF ) that erected from the underground. They start squirting something out from their top (lava probably), and... that's it.. The movie ends. I must say the ending was very stupid. I expected the military or something to grab and save them...like "ye mam we got everythin under control". There's no outcome. The FX were pretty good I must say...

### Trailer